# Adding sources to HTML5 video in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am running the following code for html5 video.

```
var media;
function videotr(){
  media = document.createElement('video');
  media.preload = true;
  media.id = 'it'; 
  document.getElementById('crop').appendChild(media)
  return media;
}                
var div = document.getElementById('crop');
$(div).empty();
this.image = new videotr();
this.image.src = args.src;
```

However, I would like to implement multiple sources for compatibility. How can add in multiple sources through java script?
I want to do this the right way, not through innerHtml.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Create a new `source` element and append it to the `video` element:

```
function addSourceToVideo(element, src, type) {
    var source = document.createElement('source');

    source.src = src;
    source.type = type;

    element.appendChild(source);
}

var video = document.createElement('video');

document.body.appendChild(video);

addSourceToVideo(video, 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv', 'video/ogg');

video.play();
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr8UH/) for it.

Comment: Thanks mate! Not only did you answer my question, but you also showed me fiddle, awesome!

I still think they should have a video.source.1 type deal so that it can be more streamlined, but I guess that's slightly against standard html.

Comment: December 2022, still works.