# Replacing HTML5 video src strings in javascript does not replace video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I'm a javascript novice building a simple page to practice using HTML5 video. It's basically a full-page looping video and a javascript timer that tracks and updates time on page. (Inspired, of course, by [Infinite Drunk Ron Swanson](http://drunkronswanson.com/)). Here is a [live version](http://ecmendenhall.github.com/Infinite-Charleston) of the page. Be careful: both links play sound.

I'd like the script to select one of seven videos to play on page load. The code should choose a random integer between 1 and 7, generate strings to the appropriate files in a "media/" directory, and replace the video `<source>` tag's `src` attribute with the new string.

This all seems to be working correctly: there are no errors in the console, locally or as uploaded to github-pages, and when I inspect the `<video>` element in the Chrome developer toolbar, I can see that the code is replacing the `src` strings correctly. But the page doesn't seem to load different videos! This is extra-aggravating, as it was working correctly a few commits ago. I've gone back through the history to see what's changed, but I can't find anything.

I come from Python, and I suspect there's something I just don't get yet, but I don't know enough to figure out what!

**UPDATE:** I have solved this problem with the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192098/adding-sources-to-html5-video-in-javascript), by using `createElement` and `appendChild` to insert the source tags instead of changing the attributes of each element in the `NodeList` returned by `querySelectorAll`. Here is the relevant new code:

```
function add_source(element, src, type) {
    var source = document.createElement("source");
    source.src = src;
    source.type = type;
    element.appendChild(source);
    }

function main() {
    var video_no = random_int(1,7);
    var video_string_mpeg = "http://ecmendenhall.github.com/Infinite-Charleston/media/Trudy" + video_no + ".mp4";
    var video_string_webm = "http://ecmendenhall.github.com/Infinite-Charleston/media/Trudy" + video_no + ".webm";
    var videoplayer = document.querySelector(".videoplayer");
    add_source(videoplayer, video_string_mpeg, "video/mp4");
    add_source(videoplayer, video_string_mpeg, "video/webm");
    get_seconds();
    }
```

This is great, but I don't completely understand why it worked. Explanations are still welcome!

Here's the javascript:

```
start = new Date();
start_time = start.getTime();

function get_seconds() {
    var now = new Date();
    var time_now = now.getTime();
    var time_diff = time_now - start_time;
    var seconds = time_diff/1000;
    var timer_string = Math.round(seconds);
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = timer_string;
    window.setTimeout("get_seconds();", 1000);
    }

function random_int(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; }


function main() {
    var video_no = random_int(1,7);
    var video_string_mpeg = "http://ecmendenhall.github.com/Infinite-Charleston/media/Trudy" + video_no + ".mp4";
    var video_string_webm = "http://ecmendenhall.github.com/Infinite-Charleston/media/Trudy" + video_no + ".webm";
    var sources = document.querySelectorAll(".videoplayer source");
    sources.item(0).src = video_string_mpeg;
    sources.item(1).src = video_string_webm;
    get_seconds();
    }
```

And the HTML:

```
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="charleston.css">
<script src="charleston.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<body onload="main();">
<video class="videoplayer" loop autoplay>
<source src="http://ecmendenhall.github.com/Infinite-Charleston/media/Trudy1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="http://ecmendenhall.github.com/Infinite-Charleston/media/Trudy1.webm" type="video/webm" />
Christ on a cracker, Trudy! Update your web browser!
<audio loop autoplay>
<source src="http://ecmendenhall.github.com/Infinite-Charleston/media/charleston.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
<source src="http://ecmendenhall.github.com/Infinite-Charleston/media/charleston.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
</video>
<div class="timer_box">
<p>Hell's bells, Trudy! You've been dancing for <a id="timer">0</a> seconds.
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't think the CSS or media files are the problem, but you can see them in the [project repository](https://github.com/ecmendenhall/Infinite-Charleston/tree/gh-pages) if you'd like. A live version is available [here](http://ecmendenhall.github.com/Infinite-Charleston/). (NB: It plays sound). As you can see, it does everything right except selecting different videos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can also call `.load()` on your video object to reload the `<source>`'s defined in the corresponding video object.

> "When your listener function is triggered, it should change the media’s src property, then call the load method to load the new media and the play method to play it, as shown in Listing 3-4." - [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html)