# HTMLAudioElement object with multiple sources

Tags: javascript, html

To create an Audio object, I simply do this:

```js
let myAudio = new Audio("myAudio.ogg")
```

But what if I have multiple sources? In HTML I can do this:

```html
<audio id="myAudio">
    <source src="myAudio.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source src="myAudio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<script>
    let myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio")
</script>
```

But I don't want to use an HTML block. Is there a way to simulate multi-source Audio with only JS?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192098/adding-sources-to-html5-video-in-javascript